# React Redux CreateSlice Post Api is not taking the updated values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an enpoint that takes formData and API gets POST method only. When the page renders it takes the initial values but I have another form to change the parameters, once I change the params it does not send the updated values.

PS. Using Redux Create Slice here is my code;

**Form Page**

```
  parametersChange = form => {
```

...  };

```
formatData = data => {
    
    return form;
  };
```

And my createSlice Method;

```
export const functionName = (data = {}) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    ........
    }));
  };
```

---

```
  this.props.getLossAvoidanceList({...data });  };

This should update my createSlice Method, however, the datain my createSlice method is always returns undefined. Where am I doing wrong ? 


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  .....
});


const mapDispatchToProps = {
  ...
};
export default connect(
 ....
)(withRouter(LossAvoidance));
```

Comment: console.log(data) find anything?

Comment: nope. returns empty object  "{}" but while sending from the component its not empty

Comment: did you use connect() function of redux? and pass mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: EDIT. I've updated my main question and added my mapStateProps to the end of the question

Comment: wrong syntax of declatation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show your code and nothing found any wrong but I think the problem is in declaration of HOC

try that way

```
import { compose } from "redux"; 

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(LossAvoidance);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot when I wrap with compose it fixed my problem ! :)